# Raise ValueError('token' or 'bot' must be passed?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am now built a PBT and now would like to start the bot service by using terminal, it is fine and can be executed in VS code perfectly so far. However, it just dont work in 'Terlminal', when I run it with

```
python3 TelegramBot.py
```

it turns out to have the following error:
'Token' or 'Bot' must be passed

[image]

Why the bot works in VS code execution but not work for terminal?
I should I do?

```
def main():
updater = Updater(API_KEY,use_context=True) #This statement is to start the bot
dp = updater.dispatcher

#Add handler here to active the trigger in here ....
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start_command))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help",help_command))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("fc",fc_check))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("caps",caps))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,handle_message))
dp.add_error_handler(error)

updater.start_polling() #Put the time interval that want the bot to check for update ,etc. 5 seconds

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

updater.idle()          #To make sure the bot continues to stay active, even nothing is happening

main()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I've tried main(bot) in the last line , but the result is the same, I have no idea how should be fixed.

Comment: Had you added token from @botfather ?

Comment: yes, I have added the API token in the variable API_KEY already

Comment: How is `API_KEY` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After I re-figure my API_KEY, then the problem is resolved, thanks @CallMeStag